# Mysql - remove data in group

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this query result:

[image]

This is what I wanna do:

IF all n post_id occurence has `user_votes==0` delete it, for exemple:

I want to delete all rows with `post_id 3086` because they all has `user_votes==0.0` .

I want to delete all rows with `post_id 3085` because they all has `user_votes==0.0` .

I don't wont delete any rows with `post_id 3060` because they got some values different from 0.0 (and i don't want delete `post_id 3060` with `user_votes 0.0` too)

I was thinking that I can sum all user_votes with same `post_id` and if result is 0.0 delete all them.
How can i do this?

Regards,
Dario

EDIT: This is sql table http://www.datafilehost.com/d/967c0109

Comment: can you post table data here? this image will be lost in that website is down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE post_id IN
(
  SELECT post_id
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY post_id
  HAVING SUM(user_votes) = 0
)
```

Or maybe the following:

```
DELETE m.*
FROM MyTable m 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT post_id
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY post_id
  HAVING SUM(user_votes) = 0
) r ON m.post_id = r.post_id
```

Comment: Just a couple of notes - he wants to delete the ones that are zero/0/ and as far as I remember in a subquery one could not reference the table one deletes from. Cheers :)

Comment: You're right, I'm working on a subquery, but if I understand how to remove the right data on an hypothetic table then I will figure out how to do a proper query with the right SELECT.

Comment: Linger, your second answer seem to work, I've to do some extra tests

Answer (score 0):

Try this on a copy of the table:

```
DELETE FROM `TABLE_NAME`
WHERE `post_id` IN (
    SELECT `post_id` FROM `TABLE_NAME` AS dummy GROUP BY `post_id` HAVING 0=SUM(`user_votes`)
)
```

Comment: Doing so I will remove all rows that has user_votes=0.0 . For example, I will remove all the rows with post_id 3060 that has 0.0 user_votes. Instead, I want to keep all rows with post_id 3060, even the ones with user_votes 0.0, just because some 'user_votes' has a value <> 0.0 in post_id 3060

Comment: @Dudo1985 - you may add *WHERE post_id != 3060* before **HAVING** caluse. Hope that helps.

Comment: Results are about 800, and I need to make a code that work dynamically, because I don't know before whic post_id has all user_votes to 0.0 and wich doesn't

Comment: @Dudo1985 - please, try my query on a copy of your data. I'm pretty confident you'll keep the lines with user_votes=0.0 and post_id = 3060. Or provide some data to test with.

Comment: ok, I've just attacched my table, pay attenction that user_votes is called just votes here

Comment: I'm sorry, I've a bad day: yes, it works! Thank you!

Comment: No no, it still works, but both solution given by Linger works, so I think it's better to accepts his answer. Thank you blue!